# Scala Spark- Peforming multiple groupby levels using Arrays as an input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my Scala program, I am dealing with a problem to combine the result from multiple levels of GroupBy. 
The dataset that I am using is quite big. As a small sample, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|  F|  L| Loy|Email|State|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
| f1| l1|loy1| null|   s1|
| f1| l1|loy1|   e1|   s1|
| f2| l2|loy2|   e2|   s2|
| f2| l2|loy2|   e3| null|
| f1| l1|null|   e1|   s3|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
```

For the **first level groupBy** I use the following script, to obtain the result based on the same **(F, L, Loy) columns**:

```
df.groupBy("F", "L", "Loy").agg(collect_set($"Email").alias("Email"), collect_set($"State").alias("State")).show
```

The result is like this:

```
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|  F|  L| Loy|   Email|State|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
| f1| l1|null|    [e1]| [s3]|
| f2| l2|loy2|[e2, e3]| [s2]|
| f1| l1|loy1|    [e1]| [s1]|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
```

The problem that I am dealing with is that how can I perform the **second level groupBy**, which is based on the condition **(F, L, Email)** and takes as an input **F** and **L** as a String while **Email** column as an Array[String]. This groupBy should return a result as followed:

```
+---+---+----+--------+---------+
|  F|  L| Loy|   Email|    State|
+---+---+----+--------+---------+
| f1| l1|loy1|    [e1]| [s3, s1]|
| f2| l2|loy2|[e2, e3]|     [s2]|
+---+---+----+--------+---------+
```

The main goal is to reduce the number of entries as much as possible by applying groupBy in different levels. I am quite new to Scala and any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use concat_ws() with null separator which will remove the Array of state to simple elements and then collect_set will get you again the array to states. Check this out.

```
scala> val df = Seq( ("f1","l1","loy1",null,"s1"),("f1","l1","loy1","e1","s1"),("f2","l2","loy2","e2","s2"),("f2","l2","loy2","e3",null),("f1","l1",null,"e1","s3")).toDF("F","L","loy","email","state")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [F: string, L: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|F  |L  |loy |email|state|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|f1 |l1 |loy1|null |s1   |
|f1 |l1 |loy1|e1   |s1   |
|f2 |l2 |loy2|e2   |s2   |
|f2 |l2 |loy2|e3   |null |
|f1 |l1 |null|e1   |s3   |
+---+---+----+-----+-----+


scala> val df2 = df.groupBy("F", "L", "Loy").agg(collect_set($"Email").alias("Email"), collect_set($"State").alias("State"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [F: string, L: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|F  |L  |Loy |Email   |State|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|f1 |l1 |null|[e1]    |[s3] |
|f2 |l2 |loy2|[e2, e3]|[s2] |
|f1 |l1 |loy1|[e1]    |[s1] |
+---+---+----+--------+-----+


scala> df2.groupBy("F","L","email").agg(max('loy).as("loy"),collect_set(concat_ws("",'state)).as("state")).show
+---+---+--------+----+--------+
|  F|  L|   email| loy|   state|
+---+---+--------+----+--------+
| f2| l2|[e2, e3]|loy2|    [s2]|
| f1| l1|    [e1]|loy1|[s3, s1]|
+---+---+--------+----+--------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks, the above solution works well for this data sample, but still the issue is that when we want groupby using every element of the list, it doesn't work. For example, the two samples: 
1:      |f1 |l1 |loy1|[e1] | [s1] | 
2:      |f1 |l1 |loy1|[e1, e2] |[s1] | 

In the groupby I want to check if any element matches with any value in the list like [e1] is contained in [e1,e2] and their first and last name is also the same, so it should groupby the records.

Comment: Sorry!.. still unclear to me... what you are mentioning here is not there in the question.. looks to be a different problem.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, will accept this answer and ask another question. Thanks!